# Is there a way we can find user in the Firebase by their Digits id/token?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

We have 2 apps (iOS and Android) which allow user to authenticate using either phone number or through Facebook.

In case of phone number it worked like this: app launched Digits authentication flow. After user submitted code from SMS, Digits SDK provided out app with the token. App sent this token to the server which looked up user by this token and responded to the app with new or existing users.

The problem is that we have to migrate our Digits users to Firebase (as Digits will stop working at 30th September). We did a migration through the Fabric console so our Fabric and Digits apps are now linked.

The problem is that even after migration there's no way to tell if the user which signed up with phone number before the migration is the same because for the same phone number Digits and Firebase SDK will give us different tokens and user IDs (as far as I understand).

Is there a way we can find user in the Firebase by their Digits id/token?

Comment: I think I'm following, but I want to confirm. You're saying after the user has migrated, you want to know the user id in Firebase based on their original Digits id? If so, I think what you're looking for is our migration helper https://github.com/firebase/digits-migration-helper-ios which will take the Digits id transform it into a Firebase token which you would then have access to use however you need.

Comment: I am sorry but I think I was mistaken. After the migration users preserved their IDs on the Firebase side, I think I will leave the question so people will know. It's pity that it wasn't mentioned in the documentation. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Gotcha, glad to hear you're all set. I'll chat with the team about clarifying the docs. Is there a specific section where you felt this was unclear?

Comment: Thank you. I guess it's worth mentioning it here https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/digits-android and here https://docs.fabric.io/android/digits/android-migration.html